# context.GetArgument() returning null with ByteGraphType

Tags: entity-framework, byte, tinyint, graphql-dotnet

I´m learning how to use CustomScalar in graphql-dotnet.

I have a tinyint column in my table and from what I have read, I´m supposed to use byte on this column in C#. After research I found out that I need to create a ByteGraphType, but I´m having trouble doing that.

I got the ByteGraphType example from this link https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-dotnet/issues/458, so I think it will work.

With this code, I can query the table, however, my mutation is not working. I didn´t find an example to demonstrate how the mutation would look like with a byte column. I tried as is stated in my code example, but in this line (var avaliacao = context.GetArgument("avaliacao");), my argument avaliacao.Nota is returning null and I´m not sure on how to proceed.

Can someone help me?

Thank you

THAT´S MY CODE

//Model

```
[Column("nota")]
public byte Nota { get; set; }
```

//Type

```
Field<ByteGraphType>("Nota", resolve: context => context.Source.Nota);
```

//InputType

```
Field<ByteGraphType>("nota");
```

//Query

```
Field<ListGraphType<AvaliacaoType>>(
    "avaliacoes",
    resolve: context => contextServiceLocator.AvaliacaoRepository.All());
```

//Mutation

```
Field<AvaliacaoType>(
    "createAvaliacao",
    arguments: new QueryArguments(
        new QueryArgument<NonNullGraphType<AvaliacaoInputType>> { Name = "avaliacao" }
    ),
    resolve: context =>
    {
        var schema = new Schema();
        schema.RegisterValueConverter(new ByteValueConverter());
        var avaliacao = context.GetArgument<Avaliacao>("avaliacao");

        avaliacao.Nota.AstFromValue(schema, new ByteGraphType());
        return contextServiceLocator.AvaliacaoRepository.Add(avaliacao);
    });
```

//ByteGraphType

```
using GraphQL.Language.AST;
using GraphQL.Types;
using System;

namespace Api.Helpers
{
    public class ByteGraphType : ScalarGraphType
    {
        public ByteGraphType()
        {
            Name = "Byte";
        }

        public override object ParseLiteral(IValue value)
        {
            var byteVal = value as ByteValue;
            return byteVal?.Value;
        }

        public override object ParseValue(object value)
        {
            if (value == null)
                return null;

            try
            {
                var result = Convert.ToByte(value);
                return result;
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public override object Serialize(object value)
        {
            return ParseValue(value).ToString();
        }

        public class ByteValueConverter : IAstFromValueConverter
        {
            public bool Matches(object value, IGraphType type)
            {
                return value is byte;
            }

            public IValue Convert(object value, IGraphType type)
            {
                return new ByteValue((byte)value);
            }
        }

        public class ByteValue : ValueNode<byte>
        {
            public ByteValue(byte value)
            {
                Value = value;
            }

            protected override bool Equals(ValueNode<byte> node)
            {
                return Value == node.Value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I need is to be able to save a record of a table that has a tinyint column. If I change the type in my code to int, I can mutate, but can´t query.

Answer (score 1):

I changed my CustomScalar and it worked:

```
using GraphQL.Language.AST;
using GraphQL.Types;
using System;

namespace Api.Helpers
{
    public class ByteGraphType : ScalarGraphType
    {
        public ByteGraphType()
        {
            Name = "Byte";
            Description = "ByteGraphType";
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public override object Serialize(object value)
        {
            return ParseValue(value).ToString();
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public override object ParseValue(object value)
        {
            byte result;
            if (byte.TryParse(value?.ToString() ?? string.Empty, out result))
            {
                return result;
            }

            return null;
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public override object ParseLiteral(IValue value)
        {
            if (value is StringValue)
            {
                return ParseValue(((StringValue)value).Value);
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```